What is the status of Rulfo's La Cordillera?
In George D. Schade's introduction to his English translation of Juan Rulfo's The Burning Plain and Other Stories, he says (bold emphasis mine):

Born in the state of Jalisco, Mexico, in 1918, Rulfo published his first short stories in the provincial little magazines of Guadalajara in the 1940's [sic]. Later on he moved to Mexico City, where the two books which have brought him such celebrity were published: his collection of short stories El llano en llamas (1953), translated here, followed by his singular short novel Pedro Paramo (1955), which Grove Press brought out in English translation. A second novel, called La Cordillera, which Rulfo evidently has been working on for several years, has long been announced as forthcoming by his Mexican publishers.

What is the status now of La Cordillera? Long after Rulfo's death, his Wikipedia page says:

The Fundación Rulfo possesses fragments of two unfinished novels, La cordillera and Ozumacín.

Has any part of La Cordillera ever been published? If so, when and where? If not, why not - was it the author's wish that his unfinished work should never be published? Even if it hasn't been published, is any information available about its contents or story?

In 1995, the publisher Ediciones Era (Mexico City) published Los cuadernos de Juan Rulfo ("Juan Rulfo's Notebooks"), which contained draft pages of what may have become La cordillera:

En este libro se pueden leer fragmentos de la novela La Cordillera, que apenas empezaba a bosquejar, pero ante cuya creación se rindió.

Quoted from Indagando a Juan Rulfo by Enrique Santos, Semanario Universidad, 19.01.2006.
Translation:

In this book you can read fragments of the novel La Cordillera, which he had just begun to outline, but before whose creation he surrendered.

Why Rulfo "surrendered" is hinted at elsewhere, in El silencio de Juan Rulfo by César Leante. The Ecuadorian author Benjamín Carrión had met Rulfo (at an unspecified date) and Rulfo had said,

le confesó a Carrión que no había seguido escribiendo La cordillera porque “había mucha sangre en ella”.

Translation:

he confessed to Carrión that he had not continued writing La cordillera because “there was too much blood in it.”

The article continues,

Lo poco que se ha filtrado de esta novela trunca —algunos pasajes de la cual aparecen en los Cuadernos— es que se desarrolla en Jalisco durante la rebelión de los “cristeros” (1925-1928). Juan Rulfo es precisamente de Jalisco y su padre fue uno de los “discípulos de Cristo” que se alzaron contra el presidente Plutarco Elías Calles cuando éste confiscó las propiedades eclesiásticas y prohibió a los curas participar en la política. El padre de Rulfo murió en la contienda.

Translation:

The little that has been come to light of this truncated novel—some passages of which appear in the Cuadernos—is that it takes place in Jalisco during the rebellion of the “Cristeros” (1925-1928). Juan Rulfo is from Jalisco and his father was one of the “disciples of Christ” who rose up against President Plutarco Elías Calles when he confiscated church property and prohibited priests from participating in politics. Rulfo’s father died in the conflict.

The most recent information about the publication status of La cordillera by the Fundación Juan Rulfo are articles dating from 2022:

La cordillera, obra inconclusa de Juan Rulfo by Reyes Martínez Torrijos, La Jornada, 9 December 2022.
La Cordillera by Roberto Chapa Martínez, Periódico El Regio, 14.12.2022.

Both article refer to Una mentira que dice la verdad, edited by Víctor Jiménez, director of the Fundación Juan Rulfo.
The first article contains the the following paragraph:

Aparte de Víctor Jiménez, director de la Fundación Juan Rulfo, Mónica Lezama le ha seguido la pista a la citada novela a través de Macario González, hijo de un ayudante de Rulfo en el Instituto Nacional Indigenista, donde se supone que escribió dicha novela y al no gustarle al terminarla, la destruyó y la tiró a la basura. Dionisio González, su padre, se dio a la tarea de pegar los pedazos minuciosamente, rescatando así, una valiosa obra.  Como muestra de la veracidad de dicha teoría, uno de los personajes de la novela, se llama Dionisio. El escrito consta de 162 páginas numeradas, 33 más que las que le llevó “Pedro Páramo”, según el original entregado por Rulfo en el Centro Mexicano de Escritores en 1954.

Translation:

Apart from Víctor Jiménez, director of the Juan Rulfo Foundation, Mónica Lezama has followed the trail of the aforementioned novel through Macario González, son of one of Rulfo's assistants at the National Indigenous Institute, where he is supposed to have written the novel and, not liking it when he finished it, destroyed it and threw it in the trash. Dionisio González, his father, took on the task of meticulously putting the pieces together, thus rescuing a valuable work. As proof of the veracity of this theory, one of the characters in the novel is called Dionisio. The text consists of 162 numbered pages, 33 more than Pedro Páramo, according to the original delivered by Rulfo to the Mexican Writers Center in 1954.

My understanding is that this is the source of the text that was published in Los cuadernos de Juan Rulfo in 1995.

Thanks for the info! Another relevant source could be Some Answers about Rulfo's la Cordillera, if you can access it.

@Randal'Thor That articles dates from 1974, 20 years before the publication of Rulfo's notebooks.
